# Position div according to another div

Tags: css, html, position, responsive-design

I have a page where there are 3 `div`s. The `div` "A" is positioned at the screen's top. The `div` "B" is positioned in the screen's center.

What I want to do is position the `div` "C" always according to the position of `div` "B" (it's a responsive page).

[image: Sample of desired outcome]

This page is under Twitter Bootstrap.

```
<div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="row-fluid secao" id="secao-home">
            <div class="row-fluid">

                <div class="span12">
                    <p class="text-center" id="contato"><a href="#">A</a></p>                                               
                </div>

                <div class="span12" id="apoio">
                    C                                   
                </div>

                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span12 text-center" id="logo">

                        <nav id="mainNav">  
                            <ul>
                                <a href="#">1</a>
                                <a href="#">2</a>
                                <a href="#">3</a>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row-fluid secao" id="secao-carros">
            <div class="span12"></div>
        </div>


        <div class="row-fluid secao" id="secao-motos">
            <div class="span12"></div>
        </div>


        <div class="row-fluid secao" id="secao-nauticos">
            <div class="span12"></div>
        </div>


        <div class="row-fluid secao" id="secao-contato">
            <div class="span12"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dU9cZ/

Can someone tell me how to do it?

Comment: what have you tries so far

Comment: Please show us your code, and a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) demo if possible.

Comment: What do you mean by `according the div "B"`? On top-right, top-left, bottom-right or bottom-left of div "B"?

Comment: Hi Morpheus! In the link above I put an image showing the position of all elements.

Comment: Hector and Arun! I'll put now the link of my application.

Comment: Please post your code as well as providing the jsfiddle links: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84342/answer-that-only-contains-a-link-to-jsfiddle

Comment: Ok! I'll learn how to use it! Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Here you can find the code in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dU9cZ/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In CSS, `absolute` positioning works relative to the most recent parent, or enclosing, element that has an explicitly set `position` attribute.  If you want a given `div`, like the one labeled "C" in your diagram, to have its position depend on another `div`, like that of "B", you should make "B" the parent of "C" by placing "C" within "B".

Then you can give "C" something like `position:absolute;right:100px;top:-30px;`, replacing the values for `right` and `top` with the desired distance from the right side of "B" and the height of "C", respectively.

If "B" is also given an explicit `position` like `position:relative` (or `absolute` or any other valid value, what matters is that you set it explicitly), then the position of "C" will be defined relative to "B".

It may seem slightly counter-inuitive that you should use `absolute` rather than `relative`, when what you want is for "C" to be "relative" to "B", but the reason for this is that CSS understands "relative" to mean "relative to the position the element would normally take in the document flow".

Comment: Hi user2074981! That's it! And it's so simple! Thank you very  much!